# Select First, Last, Min, Max Value based on Time From a List of Objects

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a List of MyObject as below:

```
public MyObject(reqVal, reqTime)
{
    _value = reqVal;
    _time = reqTime;

}

public double Value
{
     get {return _value;}
}

public DateTime Time
{
     get {return _time;}
}

var myList = new List<MyObject>();
myList.Add(new MyObject(100, new DateTime(2012, 03, 01, 10, 0, 0));
myList.Add(new MyObject(50, new DateTime(2012, 03, 01, 10, 3, 0));
myList.Add(new MyObject(10, new DateTime(2012, 03, 01, 10, 6, 0));
myList.Add(new MyObject(230, new DateTime(2012, 03, 01, 10, 9, 0));
....
```

As you  can see this list holds the values for a whole day and each value is generated every 3 min. How can I find the following based on the chunk of 15 min:

1. maxVal
2. minVal
3. openVal
4. closeVal

so if the 1st datetime value is 2012/03/01 10:00
I need to find the 4 above between 10:00 and 10:15 then next set of 4 between 10:15 and 10:30 and so on ...

so all these values will be calculated based on their time range
for example 2nd maxVal or openVal will be the maxVal and openVal between 10:15 and 10:30

any help would be much appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: Hm, openVal being the first and closeVal being the last value in the 15 minutes or...?

Comment: yes based on my last edit, all the 4 above need to be calculated based on their respective Time range, ie the maxCalculate in the first 15 min is different with the max calculated in the 2nd 15 min

Comment: Can you clarify what openVal and closeVal are?  Are they the first and last values in the 15-minute range?

Comment: yes, all the 4 values ie maxVal, minVal, openVal and closeVal are calculated within their own buckets of 15 min.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to group the list by which 15-minute interval it's in.  Here's a somewhat quick-and-dirty example (I've changed some of your values to present better test cases, and `TimeData` is the same as `MyObject`):

```
List<TimeData> myList = new List<TimeData>();
myList.Add(new TimeData(100, new DateTime(2012, 03, 01, 10, 0, 0)));
myList.Add(new TimeData(50, new DateTime(2012, 03, 01, 10, 3, 0)));
myList.Add(new TimeData(10, new DateTime(2012, 03, 01, 10, 35, 0)));
myList.Add(new TimeData(230, new DateTime(2012, 03, 01, 10, 46, 0)));

var grouped = myList.GroupBy(t => t.Time.Day.ToString()
       + "_" + t.Time.Month.ToString()
       + "_" + t.Time.Year.ToString()
       + "_" + t.Time.Hour.ToString() + "_"
       + (t.Time.Minute / 15).ToString())
   .Select(gr => new { TimeSlot = gr.Key, Max = gr.Max(item => item.Value),
         Min = gr.Min(item => item.Value),
         Open = gr.OrderBy(g => g.Time).First().Value,
         Close = gr.OrderBy(g => g.Time).Last().Value });
```

So what is happening is:

- Group by the day + month + year + hour + (minute / 15).

  - The `(t.Time.Minute / 15)` is integer division, which means that any minute value from 0 to 14 will equate to 0, 15 to 29 will be 1, and so on.
- Convert each group into a new class (I've made it anonymous for space's sake), with each group's key (the string generated in the GroupBy) and the max, min, first and last values in the group.

You could probably make this run faster by doing the `GroupBy` a bit differently (i.e. using a class as the group key instead of building a string for each one).

UPDATE: I generated myself a better test case for this by adding 10,000 elements to `myList` with random values for the value and minute.  I added a `.ToList()` on the end of the generation of `grouped` to make sure lazy evaluation wasn't a factor.  It ran in 34 milliseconds.  I tried with 100,000 elements and it ran in 226 milliseconds (as measured by a `StopWatch`).  Looks like performance isn't a huge issue unless resources are constrained and you've got hundreds of thousands of elements in `myList`.

Answer (score 3):

I would probably use something like this:

```
var end = start + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);

// Avoid querying more than once.
var matches = input.Where(x => x.Time >= start && x.Time < end)
                   .ToList();

// TODO: Consider what you want to do if there are no matches.
// (The code below would fail.)

var max = matches.Max(x => x.Value);
var min = matches.Min(x => x.Value);
var open = matches.First().Value;
var close = matches.Last().Value;
```

Using `Aggregate` you *can* do all this in one pass of the input data without creating a list... but it would be significantly more complex. Keep it simple, then benchmark to see whether this solution performs *well enough* for you.

Comment: thanks for your solution, just to clarify, this needs to be run in a loop and at each iteration add 15 min to the start date, correct?

Comment: @MaYaN: Well if you're going to run through the whole day, you could split it into chunks and just run through it *once*. Your question wasn't clear - I assumed you were writing a method which took the start time as a parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Very similar to the response by Mr. Jefferson, but returning a DateTime as the key field for grouping, as I assume you may want to chart these results.

```
List<MyObject> inputList = new List<MyObject>();

var resultSet = inputList
    .GroupBy(i => i.GetStartOfPeriodByMins(15))
    .Select( gr => 
    new { 
        StartOfPeriod = gr.Key, 
        Min = gr.Min(item => item.Value),
        Max = gr.Max(item => item.Value),
        Open = gr.OrderBy(item => item.Time).First().Value,
        Close = gr.OrderBy(item => item.Time).Last().Value
    });
```

Based on this definition of MyObject with the implementation of GetStartOfPeriodByMins on the object itself, although you could put it anywhere really:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }

    public DateTime GetStartOfPeriodByMins(int numMinutes)
    {
        int oldMinutes = Time.Minute;
        int newMinutes = (oldMinutes / numMinutes) * numMinutes;

        DateTime startOfPeriod = new DateTime(Time.Year, Time.Month, Time.Day, Time.Hour, newMinutes, 0);

        return startOfPeriod;
    }
}
```